# Cards in Materializecss is not working properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, material-design, materialize

I am trying to display the content with the cards(card reveal) from materializecss.
Ref: http://materializecss.com/cards.html

I have created three cards(with 1 row and 3 column). It is looking good in web view(pc). But in mobile view, I just need to display it in the small size to make it fit to the exact viewport. But, I don't wanna display these cards in multiple rows in the mobile view. I tried it. But, went on vain. Don't know what I am doing wrong?

Also, I could not see the content when I click the options icon in the card.

Here's the current result:

[image]

My code:

```
 <div class="parallax-container" id="abc" style="height:auto">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row center">
                    <h3 class="header col s12 white-text">Text</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col m4 s12">
                        <div class="card z-depth-4">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="activator" src="a.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                                <p><a href="#">text</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-reveal">
                                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                                <p>Text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col m4 s12">
                        <div class="card z-depth-4">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="activator" src="b.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                                <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-reveal">
                                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                                <p>Text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col m4 s12">
                        <div class="card z-depth-4">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="activator" src="c.jpeg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                                <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-reveal">
                                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                                <p>Text</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parallax cyan"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have defined s12 which means one card of one row i.e it will take complete width for one card. Make it s4 then there will be 3 cards in one row instead of multiple rows and then make styling for small screen using media query.You can check updated `code` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Rupalkataria/mcb9tLyu/#&togetherjs=5KTnRx8DSb)

For media query:[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thanks! You kinda solved 30% of the problem. I did it without media-query, that I am not allowed to use. Now, seeing the content like this! https://imgur.com/sEFUFas

Comment: Ok. Then you have to define style that fits all the width i.e in mobile,tablets and desktop.Do something like font size reduces as screen size reduces,something like this

Comment: The problem is the heading text "text"(in pic) moving down half of the way, for no reason. The font size can be the same as previous one, too.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not reproducible in a clean codepen with jQuery 3 and Materialize 0.100.2.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyvgKV

```
<div class="parallax-container" id="abc" style="height:auto">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row center">
                <h3 class="header col s12 white-text">Text</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m4 s12">
                    <div class="card z-depth-4">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img class="activator" src="a.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                            <p><a href="#">text</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <p>Text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col m4 s12">
                    <div class="card z-depth-4">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img class="activator" src="b.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                            <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <p>Text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col m4 s12">
                    <div class="card z-depth-4">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img class="activator" src="c.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                            <p><a href="#">Text</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Heading<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <p>Text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax cyan"></div>
</div>
```